# Why do we use bitwise operator?

Tags: java, algorithm

For this question http://www.codechef.com/COOK49/problems/SHOOTING/. I couldnt solve it so i followed this solution http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/4619933. Can you exlplain these steps

```
int laserNo = lasers.size();
int upLasers = 1 << laserNo;
boolean found = false;
for (int u=0; u<upLasers; u++) {
    for (int bit=0; bit<laserNo; bit++) {
        if ((u&(1<<bit)) != 0) {
            Point laser = lasers.get(bit);
```

and why do we use a bitwise operators?

Comment: Can you be more clear about parts you don't understand?

Comment: Why do people use bitwise operators in general?  Or for the solution to the problem?  Or are you wondering exactly what's going on with this code?

Comment: We use bitwise operators as they can allow us to efficiently use all the bit of an integer value.

Comment: i never got what's with the uplasers. Also 1<<laserNo is basically multiplying by 2^(laserNo) so why use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is using `u` to represent a set of integers. Each bit in `u`'s binary representation tells you if the corresponding element is in the set. For example, to check if 3 is in the set, check if `u&(1<<3) != 0' (that is, if bit number 3 is set).

By iterating from 0 to `upLasers - 1` it's essentially iterating through all possible sets of integers from 0 to `laserNo`.

This code could have used [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead, though the iteration would become much more complicated (you'd essentially end up emulating a binary increment).

Performance and instructional value are possible other reasons why it was done this way.

Comment: i get that but how does that help in this context?